# MongoDB returns different document count, when selecting the data and doing count

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-shell

I am having strange issue with sharded mongodb, when selecting data and when doing count.

I have

```
db.parts.find({"my_key":"123"}); -- I get one result back
```

but when I do

```
db.parts.find({"my_key":"123"}).count(); -- count returns 2 results.
```

I am not sure if data is corrupted or not, what is good way to verify if data is corrupted?

Comment: Use `$group` for counting on sharded clusters. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/#sharded-clusters. Not sure if you are experiencing the same issue.

Comment: Hi usearch; can you double-check that you are connecting to the mongos process, and not to any individual shard?